# Unmarshalling soap class cast exception

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, cxf

I'm following a pre-defined WSDL (and xsd) to send and recive web service calls.  The sending web service sends the object of type Any.  I'm able to send it fine.  When I receive the reply, we get a list of Any elements.  Below is the code we use:

```
        List<Object> list = academicRecordBatch.getBatchContent().getAny();
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                    Log.debug("got : "+ list.get(0).getClass().getName());
                    K12StudentType k12StudentType = (K12StudentType) list.get(0); //error on this line
        }
```

This produces the following error:
     [java] 2011-05-10 09:52:53,707 DEBUG [com.mycompany.is.Test] main(line 42): Object returned: org.pesc.message.academicrecordbatch.v2_0.AcademicRecordBatch@483bead5
     [java] java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.pesc.sector.academicrecord.v1_4.K12StudentType

Looks like what is returned is the list of ElementNSImpl.  How can I extract my  K12StudentType object from it?
I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: JAXB has generated a catch-all `getAny()` getter for your 'batchContent' property, because it may contain any elements. That is why you need to check the element type explicitly before going the cast. Provide the appropriate XSD part and XML you get before unmarshalling: maybe there will be more useful comments / ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Are you accessing a .NET webservice which returns a DataSet from a Java client? 
Anyway, try this:
Let's say the variable 'o' is showing up as a ElementNSImpl object. Cast it to a org.w3c.dom.Node object and then use DOM methods to navigate the returned XML now made available via the Node object.

```
import org.w3c.dom.*; // Add this import.

Object o = objs.get(0); // the ElementNSImpl object. 
Node dataSetNode = (Node)o;

// Some more code for illustration..            
if (dataSetNode != null) {
Node tableNode = dataSetNode.getFirstChild(); 
if (tableNode != null) {
Node dataElementNode = tableNode.getFirstChild();
        while (dataElementNode != null) {
            String text = dataElementNode.getTextContent();
            String name = dataElementNode.getNodeName();
            System.out.format("%s: %s\n", name, text);
            dataElementNode = dataElementNode.getNextSibling();
    }                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ElementNSImpl` implements the `Node` interface and this [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) explains how to unmarshal a node object.  I've never tried it though.